# Linear programming - Maximizing negative objective function

Tags: linear-programming

How can I turn this into canonical form and then use the two-phase simplex method to solve it? Would I need to add slack variable AND surplus variables?

$$\max\quad -2x_1-x_2-x_3 \\
\text{subject to: }-x_1-x_3 \le -1 \\
-x_1+x_2 \le -2 \\
-x_2+x_3 \le -1 \\
x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0
$$

When I put it into the tableau with only slack variables there are no negative coefficients in the bottom room to find the column to pivot around.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you have to add slack variables to make it a canonical form, then add artificial variables for each constraint so that in each constraint, there's one slack variable and one artificial variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to put this model into standard form, we must add slack and artificial variables. For simplicity, we'll make the righthand-side non-negative.

Thus, given the model,

$$\max\quad z=-2x_1-x_2-x_3$$
Subject to,
$$x_1+x_3\ge1$$
$$x_1-x_2\ge2$$
$$x_2-x_3\ge1$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3\ge0$$

Put in it into standardized form ([Big-M](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Ecs2035/courses/ieor3608.F05/david-bigM.pdf)) as such:

$$\max\quad z+2x_1+x_2+x_3+M(a_1+a_2+a_3)=0$$
Subject to,
$$x_1+x_3-e_1+a_1=1$$
$$x_1-x_2-e_2+a_2=2$$
$$x_2-x_3-e_3+a_3=1$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3,e_1,e_2,e_3,a_1,a_2,a_3\ge0$$

Where $M$ is an arbitrary "largest" number in $\Bbb R$.

This standard form will look like the following in the initial tableau:
\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & RHS & RT \\
\hline z & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & M & M & M & 0 & - \\
\hline ? & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & - \\
? & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & - \\
? & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & - \\ \hline 
\end{array}

Since there are no basic variables in this tableau, we'll need to make $a_1,a_2,$ and $a_3$ our initial basic variables as shown in the following tableau:
\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & RHS & RT \\
\hline z & 1 & -2M+2 & 1 & 1 & M & M & M & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4M & - \\
\hline a_1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
a_2 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
a_3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \infty \\ \hline 
\end{array}

From here, the $x_1$ column has the most negative $C^\pi_j$ for this maximization problem, thus we'll pivot and carry on like any other model via the Simplex method.